# Can't get Strings compareTo method to work

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, compareto

for some reason I can't get Strings compareTo method to work. I get this error message:

```
exception in thread main java.lang.NullpointerException
at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at Sort.main(Sort.java:27)
```

What can I do to fix this?
(this code demands that the to arrays are allready sorted individually.)

```
import java.util.*;

class Sort{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] ord = new String[6];
        ord[0] = "astra";
        ord[1] = "bilum";
        ord[2] = "deliber";
        ord[3] = "kaliber";
        ord[4] = "suppe";
        ord[5] = "vorte";

        String[] ordet = new String[6];
        ord[0] = "akilles";
        ord[1] = "kopper";
        ord[2] = "lipton";
        ord[3] = "mus";
        ord[4] = "orkester";
        ord[5] = "toving";

        String[] flettet = new String[ord.length + ordet.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < ord.length; i++){
            int teller = i; 
            for(int j = 0; j < ordet.length; j++){
                if(ord[i].compareTo(ordet[j]) > 0){ //line 27
                    teller += 1;
                }
            }
            flettet[teller] = ord[i];
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean - it looks like you are setting the wrong array:

```
    String[] ordet = new String[6];
    ordet[0] = "akilles";
    ordet[1] = "kopper";
    ordet[2] = "lipton";
    ordet[3] = "mus";
    ordet[4] = "orkester";
    ordet[5] = "toving";
```

Comment: damn! look at something to long and you get blind. hah! thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You never assign any values to ordet.  so compareTo is comparing a string to NULL

```
    String[] ord = new String[6];
    ord[0] = "astra";
    ord[1] = "bilum";
    ord[2] = "deliber";
    ord[3] = "kaliber";
    ord[4] = "suppe";
    ord[5] = "vorte";

    String[] ordet = new String[6];
    ord[0] = "akilles";                //overwriting ord[0]
    ord[1] = "kopper";                 //overwriting ord[1]
    ord[2] = "lipton";                 //overwriting ord[2]
    ord[3] = "mus";                    //overwriting ord[3]
    ord[4] = "orkester";               //overwriting ord[4]
    ord[5] = "toving";                 //overwriting ord[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

`String[] ordet = new String[6];
        ord[0] = "akilles";
        ord[1] = "kopper";
        ord[2] = "lipton";
        ord[3] = "mus";
        ord[4] = "orkester";
        ord[5] = "toving";`

You never filled the `ordet` array, you just over-wrote the `ord` array.
At this point there is no elements in the `ordet` array, just `null`s.

So...

`if(ord[i].compareTo(ordet[j]) > 0){ //line 27` 
is comparing to an element that doesnt exist, and `#compareTo` throws a NullPointerException because you passed in a `null`, not a `String`